# PHP file_get_contents fetch dynamic html td values generated using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, dynamic

I am developing a webpage where a user can add or delete rows to an HTML table.
The process is:

1. They will fill up the input widget on the webpage.
2. After filling up the description, unit, quantity, unit price, and pressing the add button; the data will be shown in the table. They will be able to add as many items as they want, and they will also be able to delete items whenever they want. Everything works fine up until here.
3. Once the user is done filling up the necessary forms, as well as adding the items they need, they will press the 'Save' button.
4. After pressing the 'Save button', I will fetch the values in the input field and the rows in the HTML table using POST method.
5. I will save the data in the database.

The dilemma is I can't fetch the rows in the table.
I researched some ways to fetch data from HTML tables using PHP, and I found out about file_get_contents function. It works perfectly fine with pre-defined tables, but not in dynamic tables.
I noticed that file_get_contents function fetches the HTML contents in the webpage, which is empty because the table will be filled when the user is using it, not when the page is created.

Now I feel like I hit the wall, and I do not have an idea for alternatives to achieve what I want.
I hope you can give me some advice. Thank you.

My webpage code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

if (isset($_POST['jo_save'])) {
    $pageContents = file_get_contents('job_order_form.php');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    $tableData = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');

    $ctr1 = 0;
    $ctr2 = 0;

    foreach ($tableData as $node) {
        $contents[$j][] = trim($node->textCotent);
        $i++;
        $j = $j % 5 == 0? $j++ : $j;
    }

    

}


?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   
    <?php require('navbar.php');?>

    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="display-4">Job Order</h3>
        <form action="<?php echo $path_parts['basename'];?>" method="POST" id="jo_information">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <label for="jo_clientName">Client Name </label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_clientName" name="jo_clientName" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="jo_date">Date(mm/dd/yyyy) </label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_date" name="jo_date" value="<?php echo date('m/d/Y');?>" readonly/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                    <label for="jo_representative">Representative</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_representative" name="jo_representative" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="jo_tin">TIN#</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_tin" name="jo_tin" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="jo_address">Address</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_address" name="jo_address" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="jo_location">Project Location</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_location" name="jo_location" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <label for="jo_creator">Created By:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_creator" name="jo_creator" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['employee_fName']." ".$_SESSION['employee_mName']." ".$_SESSION['employee_lName']?>" readonly />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <label for="jo_mobilization">Mobilization</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_mobilization" name="jo_mobilization" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <label for="jo_totalPayment">Total Payment</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="jo_totalPayment" name="jo_totalPayment" readonly/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" id="jo_save" name="jo_save">Save</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <a href="projects.php" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-danger" id="jo_cancel" name="jo_cancel">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <form action="<?php echo $path_parts['basename'];?>" method="POST" id="jo_items">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                    <label for="jo_description">Description</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_description" name="jo_description" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                    <label for="jo_unit">Unit</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="jo_unit" name="jo_unit" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                    <label for="jo_quantity">Qty.</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="jo_quantity" name="jo_quantity"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="jo_unitPrice">Unit Price</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="jo_unitPrice" name="jo_unitPrice" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                    <label for="jo_add">&nbsp</label>
                    <button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-primary" id="jo_add" name="jo_add">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="jo_item_table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unit</th>
                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr />
        </form>
            
            
        
        
        
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#jo_add").on('click', function() {
                item_amount = parseFloat($('#jo_quantity').val()*$('#jo_unitPrice').val());
                new_row = "<tr> \
                            <td>"+$('#jo_description').val()+"</td> \
                            <td>"+$('#jo_unit').val()+"</td> \
                            <td>"+$('#jo_quantity').val()+"</td> \
                            <td>"+$('#jo_unitPrice').val()+"</td> \
                            <td>"+item_amount+"</td> \
                            <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm' onClick='deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button></td>";
                            

                jo_items_tbl = $('table tbody');
                jo_items_tbl.append(new_row);
                $('#jo_totalPayment').val(computeTotal);
                $('#jo_description').val("");
                $('#jo_unit').val("");
                $('#jo_quantity').val("");
                $('#jo_unitPrice').val("");
                
            });
        });

        function deleteRow(cell){
            var row = $(cell).parents('tr');
            var rIndex = row[0].rowIndex;
            document.getElementById('jo_item_table').deleteRow(rIndex);
        }

        function computeTotal(){
            
            var totalAmount = 0.0;
            var tbl = document.getElementById('jo_item_table');
            
            for(var row=1, n=tbl.rows.length; row<n; row++){
                totalAmount += parseFloat(tbl.rows[row].cells[4].innerHTML);
            }

            return totalAmount;

        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some screenshots of the webpage:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1wYH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TasD.png)

Comment: Don't put the data into plain table cells then, put them into _input fields_ - then you can simply submit that form the whole table is in, to get the data send to the server. You can make the input fields `readonly`, if the user is not supposed to change the values contained in them. (They still _could_ change them using dev tools for example, so if the results of those calculations are important and need to be protected against manipulation, then you would have to do the calculation on the server side, again.)

Comment: If you want the data display to look a certain way that can't be achieved with input fields, then you can of course also put normal text into the table cells, and add _hidden_ input fields to transport the actual data.

Comment: you have to do that with JavaScript and send the new rows to php, you can read here to see some example code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780109/how-to-get-the-values-from-dynamically-created-rows-and-store-all-the-column-and/51780629

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a database (sqlite, mysql), or if you really want to use files, use [CSV](https://roytuts.com/read-from-and-write-to-a-csv-file-using-php/).

```
$file_name = "file.csv";

if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo $data[0] . $data[1] . $data[2];
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$fp = fopen($file_name, 'a');
// data to write
$infos = ["abc", "123"];
foreach ($infos as $info) {
    fputcsv($fp, array($info));
}
fclose($fp)
```

Edit: "5: I will save the data in the database."

In that case, you can fetch the records from the database, no need to read from files.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I already have set-up the database for the webpage. The problem I'm experiencing is that I need to fetch the values from the table, then save those values to the database.
I don't know how to get the values from the html table and save them to a PHP variables or array.

Comment: I believe that your approach might be a bit wrong; since you aren't updating html file on server, file_get_contents() won't work;

Comment: You can, however, save the form data in a javascript array when "add" is pressed, and when submit is pressed, call a function where you send all of that data to a php script through $_POST, there you will receive data and send it to db